# $f$ is holomorphic iff $df$ is $\Bbb C$-linear

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb C^n$ open connected, $f:\Omega\to\Bbb C$ differentiable in the real sense. We know that $f$ is holomorphic iff $\partial_{\bar z_j}f=0\;\;\forall j=1,\dots,n$ .

We know also that $df=\partial_zfdz+\partial_{\bar z}f d\bar z=:\partial f+\bar{\partial}f$.

How can I prove from this that $f$ is holomorphic iff $df$, which is in general $\Bbb R$-linear, is now $\Bbb C$-linear?

We know by definition that such an $f$ is differentiable in the complex sense in $w\in\Omega$ iff $\;\exists\; T:\Bbb C^n\to\Bbb C$ $\Bbb C$-linear such that
$$
\lim_{z\to w,z\in\Omega}\frac{f(z)-f(w)-T(z-w)}{||z-w||_{\Bbb C^n}}=0
$$
and being $T=df$ we can conclude. But I would like to prove it directly, using that $df=\partial f+\bar{\partial}f$, showing that $df$ is $\Bbb C$-linear iff $\bar{\partial}f=0$.

Even because trying in different ways it seems that $df$ be always $\Bbb C$-linear, and this is wrong, so showing what I've asked I'd shed some lights on this.

Can somebody give me some hints? Many thanks!

Comment: It's important to note that an $\Bbb R$-linear map $T : V\to W$ of complex vector spaces has a unique decomposition as $T_1 + T_2$, where $T_1$ is $\Bbb C$-linear and $T_2$ is complex anti-linear. Consider that $\partial f$ is $\Bbb C$-linear and $\bar{\partial}f$ is anti-linear.

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks! But $\partial f=\partial_zfdz$ and $\bar{\partial}f=\partial_{\bar z}fd\bar z$ and so to check 
$\partial f$ is linear and  $\bar{\partial}f$ is antilinear it would be suffice to check it for $dz$ and $d\bar z$ resp. Right? And here I'm stuck:  (we use the identification $\Bbb C^n\simeq\Bbb C^n\times\bar{\Bbb C^n}$) let $n=1$, then $dz=[1,i]$ and $d\bar z=[1,-i]$; but in this way I get $dz(iz,\overline{iz})=id\bar z(z,\bar z)$!! So I didn't get neither linearity of $dz$ nor antilinearity of $d\bar z$ (which would allow me to conclude)! Can you help me please?

Comment: The form $dz$ is identified with $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $d\bar{z}$ is identified with $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$. Also, $i$ is identified with $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$. You can check via multiplication the identified matrices that $dz\cdot i = i\cdot dz$ and $d\bar{z}\cdot i = -i\cdot d\bar{z}$, which imply linearity of $dz$ and anti-linearity of $d\bar{z}$, respectively.  Then linearity of $\partial f$ and anti-linearity of $\bar{\partial}f$ follow.

Comment: Man! Copy paste it down here as answer! I'd like to give you the points you deserve! Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form $dz$ is identified with $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and the form $d\bar{z}$ is identified with $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$. Also, $i$ is identified with $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$. You can check via multiplication of the identified matrices that $dz\cdot i = i\cdot dz$ and $d\bar{z} = -i\cdot d\bar{z}$, which establish the $\Bbb C$-linearity of $dz$ and anti-linearity of $d\bar{z}$, respectively. Then the $\Bbb C$-linearity of $\partial f$ and anti-linearity of $\bar{\partial} f$ follow. Thus, $df$ is $\Bbb C$-linear $\iff$ $\bar{\partial} f$ is $\Bbb C$-linear $\iff $ $\bar{\partial}f = 0$  $\iff$ $\partial_{\bar{z}}f = 0$ $\iff$ $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Maybe you'd write $\bar{\partial}f=0$, not that it's $\Bbb C$-linear...or not?

Comment: Actually @Joe, saying $\bar{\partial} f$ is $\Bbb C$-linear at the end is right. Since $\partial f$ is $\Bbb C$-linear, $d f$ is $\Bbb C$-linear if and only if $df - \partial f$ is $\Bbb C$-linear, i.e., $\overline{\partial} f$ is $\Bbb C$-linear.

Comment: Yeah, you're right... but it's not intuitive as saying $\bar{\partial}f=0$, IMHO

Comment: Or, even, being $\bar{\partial}f$ antilinear, it's linear iff it's $0$ and we're again done! :-) Thanks again!