# Mistake in proof that $f$ is holomorphic iff $df$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, solution-verification, complex-geometry

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ differentiable. I have already seen [the proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236038/f-is-holomorphic-iff-df-is-bbb-c-linear) that $f$ is holomorphic (by definition meaning that $\partial_{\overline{z}}f = 0$) iff $d_p f: T_p\mathbb{C} \rightarrow T_{f(p)}\mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear, so it's **not a proof** that I'm asking for, but rather where does **my attempt** of a proof **go wrong**?

For a fixed point $p$ in the manifold $\mathbb{C}$, identify $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \in T_p\mathbb{C}$ with $1:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, i:=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. Then for any $v=v_x+iv_y \in T_p\mathbb{C}$, $d_p f(v_x + i v_y) = v_x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p) + i v_y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)$. $\mathbb{C}$-linearity means that $d_p f( (a+bi)(v_x+iv_y)) = (a+bi)d_p f(v_x +iv_y)$.
$$
LHS=(av_x-bv_y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p) + i (av_y + bv_x) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)
$$
$$
RHS = av_x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p) - bv_y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)
+ i (bv_x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p) + av_y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p))
$$

So we have $\mathbb{C}$-linearity $\Leftrightarrow$ $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p)$, which is clearly false. Where am I being a fool?

Comment: I guess $p=v_x+iv_y$. For $d_pf$ we would rather have $d_pf=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.

Comment: No, $v = v_x+iv_y$ is any vector in $T_p \mathbb{C}$; I edited for clarity

Comment: $d_p f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ indeed, this equality just means $d_p f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$

Comment: @rosecabbagedragon: One problem is that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p)$ is a complex number, not a real number (being the limit of $\frac{f(p + t) - f(p)}{t}$ where $t$ is real and $f(p+t),f(p)$ are complex) so your comparison of "real and imaginary" parts does not work.

Comment: @levap That IS the problem. Just as silly as I expected. Thank you very much. (Transitioning from a lot of real geometry to complex one, this was unexpectedly easy to overlook.)